# Create prioritization matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have the data below that create feasibility data and business value data and Im trying to create the optimization matrix  as I attach below but im not sure how to process the data for this. Im not sure if multiply each value of every row as I do I have to add each value of the same column

```
# Create the dataframe
data_values <- c("Existing Customers Data", "Prospect Data", "Customer Activity", "Sales History")
customer_profile <- c(4, 3, 4, 4)
heterogeneity <- c(4, 3, 3, 4)
portfolio_quality <- c(4, 3, 4, 4)

# Combine the data into a dataframe
bv_data <- data.frame(
  `Business Values` = data_values,
  `Customer Profile` = customer_profile,
  `Heterogeneity` = heterogeneity,
  `Portfolio Quality` = portfolio_quality
)
```

[image]

```
# Create the dataframe
feasibility <- c("Existing Customers Data", "Prospect Data", "Customer Activity", "Sales History")
availability <- c(4, 1, 3, 4)
quality_of_data <- c(4, 1, 3, 4)
depth_of_data <- c(4, 1, 3, 4)
price <- c(4, 4, 4, 4)

# Combine the data into a dataframe
feasibility_data <- data.frame(
  `Feasibility` = feasibility,
  `Availability` = availability,
  `Quality of data` = quality_of_data,
  `Depth of data` = depth_of_data,
  `Price` = price
)
```

[image]

**my process**

```
colnames(bv_data)[1]<-"Items"

# Select only the numeric columns for multiplication
numeric_data <- bv_data[, sapply(bv_data, is.numeric)]

# Function to perform row-wise multiplication
row_multiply <- function(row) {
  prod(row)
}

# Apply row-wise multiplication
row_multiplication <- apply(numeric_data, 1, row_multiply)

# Create a new column in the optimization matrix with the row-wise multiplication results
bv_data$Business.Values <- row_multiplication

bv_data<-bv_data[,c(1,5)]



colnames(feasibility_data)[1]<-"Items"

# Select only the numeric columns for multiplication
numeric_data <- feasibility_data[, sapply(feasibility_data, is.numeric)]

# Function to perform row-wise multiplication
row_multiply <- function(row) {
  prod(row)
}

# Apply row-wise multiplication
row_multiplication <- apply(numeric_data, 1, row_multiply)

# Create a new column in the optimization matrix with the row-wise multiplication results
feasibility_data$Feasibility <- row_multiplication

feasibility_data<-feasibility_data[,c(1,6)]


# Assuming 'bv_data' and 'feasibility_data' are the previously created dataframes

# Merge the dataframes based on the common column ('Business Values' and 'Feasibility')
optimization_matrix <- merge(bv_data, feasibility_data, by="Items")

# Calculate Priority (Effort * Impact)
optimization_matrix$Priority <- optimization_matrix$Business.Values*optimization_matrix$Feasibility


optimization_matrix$Label<-c("D","A","B","C")




library(ggplot2)


# Create the plot
ggplot(optimization_matrix, aes(x = Feasibility, y = Business.Values, label = Label)) +
  xlim(-256, 256) + ylim(-80, 80) + geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(Label %in% c("C", "A"), ifelse(Label == "C", "C", "A"), Label)), 
            vjust = ifelse(optimization_matrix$Label == "A", 1.8, 2.9), hjust = -0.5) +
  labs(title = "Optimization Matrix",
       x = "Feasibility",
       y = "Business Values") +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]